# Ordering database results in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

If there is input new data into the mysql field automatically appears in the top instead of at the bottom. In my chat application messages coming out of the bottom, so whenever there is a new message he presented below, how can new messages appear at the top instead of at the bottom?

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("agency");
    $select = "SELECT * FROM input"; 
    $query = mysql_query($select);
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo $data['message'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

for example:

```
A: hello

B: also
```

I want to order

```
B: also

A: hello
```

so the message appears from above, rather than below.

Comment: You will have to use an `ORDER BY` clause in your sql query. It's impossible to tell how your query should look without knowing the structure of the table.

Comment: please give a little enlightenment, how to make it, I am not an expert about mysql

Comment: Please do not use the `mysql_*` functions in PHP. They are deprecated. See http://www.phptherightway.com/#mysql_extension

Comment: You need to edit your question and add the structure of the table `input`

Comment: message  varchar(60) latin1_swedish_ci  No None

Comment: I updated my answer  have a look at it

Comment: @nasa http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm

Comment: @Robert: thank you very helpful reference

Comment: You are not making any check to see if the connection or query succeeded. The errors you report in the comments below are a result of one of these failing. Add these checks in to help you debug your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give order by id **DESC**

```
select * from table_name order by id DESC
```

Comment: after thoroughly tested and it turns your code correctly, the problem should make the id column and set the order by [id] desc..

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    Change

    $select = "SELECT * FROM input"; 

    to

    $select = "SELECT * FROM input ORDER BY id DESC"; 

    Or

   $select = "SELECT * FROM input ORDER BY DATE(inserted_at) DESC";
```

Comment: However, would consider to order it by `date inserted` (if available)

Comment: @Robert We don't have the table structure

Comment: @Hudixt Yeah I know, thats why I made a comment that it just should be CONSIDERED...

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\agent2456\include\chatlogy.inc.php on line 9

Comment: did have id field in your table

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use Order by desc. use the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<title>GOOD CHANGE</title>
</head><body><?php
include_once("connect.db.php");
$database::selectdb('agency');
$select = "SELECT * FROM input Order by id desc"; 
  $query = mysql_query($select);
  while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
      echo $data['message']; // Will give you the desired output
      echo "<br>";
  }
  ?>
</body></html>
```

**Note*: Dont use mysql_* function, use PDO or mysqli prepared statements instead.**

Hope this helps you

Comment: Should be DESC as he wants the latest ones first.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you will use date inserted with DESC.
Like

```
SELECT * FROM table_name order by date_inserted DESC
```

Comment: I the table contains an auto_incremented column named id, `ORDER BY id DESC` would produce the same result.

Comment: If id is auto_incremented then it's fine otherwise date&time is the safe way to doing it.

Comment: Yes, but I would still recommend a table structure with a primary key that is auto incremented. It would also be used as an index in that case which would speed things up.

Comment: Yes, but I am saying if you don't have an auto_incremented id then it will be safest way to do and if you want you can provide index for date&time also.